# Get latest message from chat conversations

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table which contains all messages created by users:

```
Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->text('text');
    $table->foreignIdFor(User::class, 'sender_id');
    $table->foreignIdFor(User::class, 'receiver_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now I try to create something like messenger contacts list - I must get all conversations and their latest messages (only one latest message from each chat), but I don't know how to do it by one query.

Please help.

Comment: This question is a pretty common question on Stack Overflow, often tagged with [tag:greatest-n-per-group]. I suggest you click on that tag link and see some of the many answers posted.

Comment: But in Laravel I see its pretty harder. I don't see good solution for Eloquent